# comparing datetime ranges in python

Tags: python, json, datetime

I have a set of datetimes that defines times for running a particular job. I'm wondering what is the best way to compare them.

Example:

I have a list:

```
jobs_to_run = [datetime (2016,06,04,12,20,00000), datetime (2016,06,01,12,20,00000)]
```

I want to compare it with other set of dates and running times from a JSON file (single entry unpacked below in example). Each list entry comes with two datetimes - one for start date and one for end date:

```
running_start_time = datetime(2016,06,04,08,10,00000) 
running_end_time = datetime(2016,06,10,08,08,00000)
```

What I want to do is to check if `jobs to run` lies within the entries from `running_times`. My current approach is to save `running_times` (I have more than one entry for running_times), in dict:

```
{'running_time1': [datetime(2016,06,04,08,10,00000), datetime(2016,06,10,08,08,00000)], 'running_time2': [datetime(2016,06,04,01,10,00000), datetime(2016,06,02,08,08,00000)]}
```

and compare it in a loop with my jobs to run:

```
for key in running_times:
    for i in jobs_to_run:
        if running_times[key][0] <= i <= running_times[key][1]:
            print "job to run is in range so we can run it"
        else:
            print "job to run is out of range so we can't run it"
```

Is there a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: Probably better to post this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is `d` ? What is `x` ? Can you name your variable with meaningfull names please ? Can you post a fully reproducible example ?

Comment: thanks @JulienPalard for your comment, I edited my question and hope its more readable now

Comment: @user1762447 As far as I understand it - You need not to nest `for i jobs_to_run`(You have single job with two timestamps) - or if You do (You have multiple jobs, each with two ts), it should be i[0] (since only starting time is important)?